# How to bind data in a UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

This is not a duplicate (I hope). I have spent the last 2 hours searching both Google and SO to to avail. I am trying to bind the `TextBlock.Text` property to some public properties on my user control, as shown below:

```
### Multimeter Overview Usercontrol Code Behind ###

public partial class MultimeterOverview : UserControl
{
    public string MeterName { get; set; }
    public int GoodPackets { get; set; }
    public int InvalidPackets { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan ElapsedTime { get; set; }
    public double MaxValue { get; set; }
    public double MinValue { get; set; }
    public double CurrentValue { get; set; }
    public string CurrentUnits { get; set; }
    public string CurrentStatus { get; set; }

    public Multimeter multimeter;
    public MainWindow program;

    public MultimeterOverview() //This method is not called...at all.
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    public MultimeterOverview(MainWindow reference, Multimeter multi) //This one is called
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        program = reference;
        multimeter = multi;
    }
}
```

And with irrelevant code removed for brevity:

```
### Multimeter Overview Class XAML ###

<UserControl x:Name="Overview" x:Class="jLogger.MultimeterOverview"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:properties="clr-namespace:jLogger.Properties"
         xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
         xmlns:d3="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Research.DynamicDataDisplay;assembly=DynamicDataDisplay"
         xmlns:d3e="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Research.DynamicDataDisplay.Charts;assembly=DynamicDataDisplay"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         d:DesignHeight="110" d:DesignWidth="300" MinWidth="300">

           <Grid>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" FontSize="20" FontFamily="Segoe UI Semilight" Margin="5, 0, 0, 0" Foreground="{StaticResource AccentColorBrush}" Text="{Binding MeterName}"/>

                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Status:" Foreground="{StaticResource AccentColorBrush}" Padding="5,2,2,2"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ElementName=Overview, Path=CurrentStatus, Mode=TwoWay}" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5, 0, 0, 0"/>

                <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="Elapsed Time:" Foreground="{StaticResource AccentColorBrush}" Padding="5,2,2,2"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ElementName=Overview, Path=ElapsedTime}" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5, 0, 0, 0"/>

                <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Content="Good Packets:" Foreground="{StaticResource AccentColorBrush}" Padding="5,2,2,2"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ElementName=Overview, Path=GoodPackets}" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5, 0, 0, 0"/>

                <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Content="Invalid Packets:" Foreground="{StaticResource AccentColorBrush}" Padding="5,2,2,2"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ElementName=Overview, Path=InvalidPackets}" Foreground="Black" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5, 0, 0, 0"/>
            </Grid>
    </UserControl>
```

This control is dynamically loaded into a `Grid` inside a `ScrollViewer`. I then set the value of both the `MeterName` and `CurrentStatus` (Both of which are using different bindings, in an attempt to try and get it working). However, the UI does not update, and the values are not displayed. However I have confirmed that the value gets set, by printing the `MultimeterOverview.CurrentStatus` and `MeterName`, and they both contain the correct values.

Does anyone know how I can successfully bind my `UserControl UI` to my `UserControl`? I have tried:

```
1. <UserControl ... DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
2. this.DataContext = this; //In MultimeterOverview
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are `setting the values once UserControl gets loaded`.

You need to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface on class `MultimeterOverview` so that UI gets notified on any property change in class object.

Sample property:

```
private string meterName;
public string MeterName
{
   get
   {
      return meterName;
   }
   set
   {
      if(meterName != value)
      {
         meterName = value;
         OnPropertyChanged("MeterName");
      }
   }
}
```

You need to make other properties to follow the same syntax like mentioned above.

Comment: I eventually found this out :D But thank you for your answer. For future reference, this is the solution! I should note, you can write it all in one line: `public string MeterName { get { return meterName; } set { meterName = value; OnPropertyChanged("MeterName"); } }`

Comment: Yeah, i just intend it to give better look. Intended code looks good to me.

Answer (score 0):

Standard properties do not support binding. You need implement your properties as dependency properties. Your XAML is ok. The DataContext needs to be untouched so that the control can "see" the DataContext of its parent.

Comment: I use almost the exact same code for my other UserControls, and they are working fine. I suspect it is due to the list box maybe?